# How to tweak MapFragment (Android)

Tags: java, android, dictionary, fragment, marker

I have made a MapFragment which basically is GoogleMaps. This Fragment is called in an activity, through the fragmentManager and fragment transaction. I would like to tweak my Map now to add some markers and dynamic zoom aswell. I am a bit struggling with this at the moment. Maybe some of you can take a look and help out.

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

Context context;
Button showMap;
Button showMyLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    context = this;

    showMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showMap);
    showMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            MapFragment mf = new MapFragment();
            MapFragment.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("2.900000"), Double.parseDouble("1.55555")))
            .title("oh yeah"));
            ft.add(R.id.maps_layout, mf);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    showMyLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showMyLocation);
    showMyLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

public static GoogleMap googleMap;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    googleMap = ((com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}


 }
```

After updating to the code above it gives me this error in the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dell.exampleapplication.MapsActivity$1.onClick(MapsActivity.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

This may provide extra information for help.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: I already found numerous tutorial on how to add the marker and zoom in, but i don't understand the logic of how getting control over my map, if you could explain to me would be helpfull.

Comment: just asking why did you add the button "show my location " ,google map already has one , you have just to enable it

Comment: I am experimenting with this at the moment, adding it dynamically based on your updated location seemed interesting for me. But that is not the problem here, the problem is how to invoke the map and how to tweak it (dont understand the logic of control or finding the view).

Comment: sorry i'm not english, i found it hard to understand what you mean, do you need how to use google maps in fragment ?

Comment: Yes how use google maps in fragment, how to add marker. I need that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is how i use it:

```
public class Mapfrag2 extends Fragment{
    public static   GoogleMap map;
    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout, container, false);}

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    
        map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
      
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(30.76793169992044, 1.98180484771729));//moving the map to defined position
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);
            map.moveCamera(center);
            markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            map.animateCamera(zoom);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                   //doing something when pressing marker's bubble
                }
            });
        }

    }

   
    
    

   

   

}
```

in your activity just call

```
 MapFrag2.map
```

### example

adding markers from activity

```
Mapfrag2.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon)))
                        .title(title).snippet(snippet));
```

clearing the map

```
 Mapfrag2.map.clear();
```

### Edit 2

try to change this part of code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            MapFragment mf = new MapFragment();
            MapFragment.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("2.900000"), Double.parseDouble("1.55555")))
            .title("oh yeah"));//move this to the end
            ft.add(R.id.maps_layout, mf);
            ft.commit();
           //here you add your marker
        }
```

Comment: I tried but i still get errors, check update code + stacktrace if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same, ami i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution very easy. I just followed the steps in this wiki page (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Google_Maps_Android_API_in_Android_Studio). It basically explains everything to you.

Simple tip: make your MapActivity extend FragmentActivity !